# can we use today and tomorrow idiomatically?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is it possible to use tomorrow to mean future in an idiomatic language? In my mother language we can say:

1. **today** to mention current time
2. **tomorrow** to mention near future

For example, I used today and tomorrow for current time and near future in the following sentence.

> In the era of technological evolution, the pace of changes is so fast
> that **today’s** renovations will become obsolete **tomorrow**.

Is it correct to used these words this way? Actually does it mean the same as what follows?

> In the era of technological evolution, the pace of changes is so fast
> that **current** renovations will become obsolete **in near future**.

Comment: Make sure you actually mean "renovations" and not "innovations." As I don't know the full context, "renovations" could be correct, but in the given context, it seems like "innovations" is what you actually mean, not "renovations."

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Thanks for the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your example uses "today" and "tomorrow" metaphorically, and that is in line with common usage—as you would know if you had looked in a dictionary.

> [**today**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/today#English), adjective
> 2. In the current era; nowadays.

> [**tomorrow**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tomorrow#English), adjective
> 2. At some point in the future; later on